# Como utilizar esse script para uma lista de servidores? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou utilizando este código para atualizar alguns servidores aqui na minha empresa, via ssh:

http://alissonmachado.com.br/python-e-ssh/

na linha 11, temos:

`self.ssh.connect(hostname='ip_do_servidor',username='Administrator',password='senha_servidor')`

e na linha 22, temos:

```
ssh.exec_cmd("update image force http://link_FTP")
```

A dúvida é a seguinte: Como faço para rodar esse comando em nao um, mas em vários servidores ao mesmo tempo? uma lista.

Answer (score 2):

É <strike>impossível</strike> muito difícil garantir que o comando seja executado em todos os servidores ao mesmo tempo.

Mas, como se trata de um recurso externo, você pode utilizar o módulo `asyncio` para gerenciar as tarefas através de corotinas. Desta forma, seu código tenderá a executar mais rápido que se fizesse sequencial.

Se tiver uma lista de servidores, com usuário e senha, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
import asyncio, asyncssh

async def update_image_force(host, user, pass):
    async with asyncssh.connect(host, username=user, password=pass) as ssh:
        await ssh.run('update image force http://link_FTP')

commands = asyncio.gather(*[update_image_force(server_data) for server_data in server_list])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(commands)
```

A documentação do AsyncSSH pode ser vista aqui: http://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Já o módulo `asyncio` é nativo do Python para versões superiores a 3.6.

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal. Na verdade, eu quis dizer: Roda comando em um, depois outro, depois outro, depois outro.. Sem a necessidade de eu ficar colocando o IP.

Answer (score 0):

Use uma estrutura de repetição como o `for`:

```
meus_servidores = [
    ('ip_do_servidor1', 'Administrator', 'senha_servidor1'),
    ('ip_do_servidor2', 'Administrator', 'senha_servidor2'),
    ('ip_do_servidor3', 'Administrator', 'senha_servidor3'),
    ('ip_do_servidor4', 'Administrator', 'senha_servidor4'),
]

for servidor, usuario, senha in meus_servidores:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=servidor, username=usuario, password=senha)
    ssh.exec_command("update image force http://link_FTP")
```