# Como executar esse script de uma maneira mais sofisticada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

Bom dia.

Estou usando este código para atualizar a firmware dos servidores da minha empresa.

Porém, queria usar esse mesmo código, para atualizar uma lista de servidores, não apenas um.

Segue o código original:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko

    class SSH:
            def __init__(self):
                self.ssh = SSHClient()
                self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
                self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                self.ssh.connect(hostname='blhp0032.locaweb.com.br',username='Administrator',password='SenhaServidor')

            def exec_cmd(self,cmd):
                stdin,stdout,stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
                if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
                    print stderr.read()
                else:
                    print stdout.read()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ssh = SSH()
        ssh.exec_cmd("update image force http://firmware.tecnologia.ws/firmware/hpoa485.bin")
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Tentei adaptar o código para atualizar uma lista, utilizando comandos do Ubuntu, mas não obitve êxito. Segue código modificado:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko
import sys

    class SSH:
        def processar(ip):

            def __init__(self):
                self.ssh = SSHClient()
                self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
                self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                self.ssh.connect(hostname=ip,username='Administrator',password='SenhaServidor')

            def exec_cmd(self,cmd):
                stdin,stdout,stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
                if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
                    print stderr.read()
                else:
                    print stdout.read()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ssh = SSH()
        ssh.exec_cmd("update image force http://firmware.tecnologia.ws/firmware/hpoa485.bin")


        if __name__ == "__main__":
            for ip in sys.argv[1:]: 
                processar(ip)
```

Porém, quando o rodo comando no terminal `cat lista.txt | xargs script.py` ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_oa_teste.py", line 24, in <module>
    ssh.exec_cmd("update image force http://firmware.tecnologia.ws/firmware/hpoa485.bin")
AttributeError: SSH instance has no attribute 'exec_cmd'
```

Lembrando que criei um arquivo .txt no mesmo diretório do script, contendo a lista de servidores na qual quero rodar o comando SSH do script.

Me ajudem, por favor.

Obrigado!!

Comment: Conhece a biblioteca Fabric?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código com a indentação correta na pergunta? A indentação incorreta pode ser a causa do erro.

Comment: Aliás, você já havia perguntado praticamente isso em [Como utilizar esse script para uma lista de servidores? - Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320490/5878)

Comment: Ansible, pode mudar a sua vida. Da uma olhada. Tenha um óptimo dia.

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa complicar tanto, é só colocar `ip` como parâmetro do `__init__` da sua classe original mesmo, sem criar mais subníveis:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko
import sys

class SSH:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ssh = SSHClient()
        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect(hostname=ip, username='Administrator',password='SenhaServidor')

    def exec_cmd(self,cmd):
        stdin,stdout,stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        #if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
        #    print stderr.read()
        #else:
        #    print stdout.read()
        return stdin, stdout, stderr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []

    for ip in sys.argv[1:]:
        ssh = SSH(ip)
        result = ssh.exec_cmd("update image force http://firmware.tecnologia.ws/firmware/hpoa485.bin")
        results.append(result)

    for stdin, stdout, stderr in results:
        if stderr.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
            print stderr.read()
        else:
            print stdout.read()
```

Além disso, uma outra modificação foi tirar a recuperacão de resultados do `exec_cmd`, para evitar que o método fique esperando resultados de um dos servidores. Do jeito que eu fiz, ele vai enviar o comando para todos os servidores primeiro, e depois espera os resultados, assim, o comando executa de forma simultânea em todos os servidores.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. 

Realmente, era bem simples mesmo hahahaha